# vectoring pandas df by row with multiple conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, vectorization

I'm trying to avoid for loops applying a function on a per row basis of a pandas df. I have looked at many vectorization examples but have not come across anything that will work completely. Ultimately I am trying to add an additional df column with the summation of successful conditions with a specified value per each condition by row.

I have looked at np.apply_along_axis but that's just a hidden loop, np.where but I could not see this working for 25 conditions that I am checking

```
              A         B         C  ...         R         S         T
0  0.279610  0.307119  0.553411  ...  0.897890  0.757151  0.735718
1  0.718537  0.974766  0.040607  ...  0.470836  0.103732  0.322093
2  0.222187  0.130348  0.894208  ...  0.480049  0.348090  0.844101
3  0.834743  0.473529  0.031600  ...  0.049258  0.594022  0.562006
4  0.087919  0.044066  0.936441  ...  0.259909  0.979909  0.403292

[5 rows x 20 columns]

def point_calc(row):
    points = 0
    if row[2] >= row[13]:
        points += 1
    if row[2] < 0:
        points -= 3
    if row[4] >= row[8]:
        points += 2
    if row[4] < row[12]:
        points += 1
    if row[16] == row[18]:
        points += 4
    return points

points_list = []
for indx, row in df.iterrows():
    value = point_calc(row)
    points_list.append(value)

df['points'] = points_list
```

This is obviously not efficient but I am not sure how I can vectorize my code since it requires the values per row for each column in the df to get a custom summation of the conditions.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

UPDATE:
I was able to get a little more speed replacing the df.iterrows section with df.apply.

```
df['points'] = df.apply(lambda row: point_calc(row), axis=1)
```

UPDATE2:
I updated the function as follows and have substantially decreased the run time with a 10x speed increase from using df.apply and the initial function.

```
def point_calc(row):
    a1 = np.where(row[:,2]) >= row[:,13], 1,0)
    a2 = np.where(row[:,2] < 0, -3, 0) 
    a3 = np.where(row[:,4] >= row[:,8])
    etc.
    all_points = a1 + a2 + a3 + etc.
    return all_points

df['points'] = point_calc(df.to_numpy())
```

What I am still working on is using np.vectorize on the function itself to see if that can be improved upon as well.

Comment: What's the size of your dataframe?

Comment: The size varies. Usually no more that 100k records with 40 columns but the number of conditions could grow to 100

Comment: A side note: you can just write df.apply(point_calc, axis=1) rather than using a lambda expression in your solution.

Comment: Nice! Thank you @GZ0 ,shaved off more time. 100ms faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it it the following way:

```
# this is a small version of your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

It looks like that:

```
    A           B           C           D
0   0.724198    0.444924    0.554168    0.368286
1   0.512431    0.633557    0.571369    0.812635
2   0.680520    0.666035    0.946170    0.652588
3   0.467660    0.277428    0.964336    0.751566
4   0.762783    0.685524    0.294148    0.515455
5   0.588832    0.276401    0.336392    0.997571
6   0.652105    0.072181    0.426501    0.755760
7   0.238815    0.620558    0.309208    0.427332
8   0.740555    0.566231    0.114300    0.353880
9   0.664978    0.711948    0.929396    0.014719
```

You can create a Series which counts your points and is initialized with zeros:

```
points = pd.Series(0, index=df.index)
```

It looks like that:

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    0
dtype: int64
```

Afterwards you can add and subtract values line by line if you want:
The condition within the brackets selects the rows, where the condition is true.
Therefore `-=` and `+=` is only applied in those rows.

```
points.loc[df.A < df.C] += 1
points.loc[df.B <    0] -= 3
```

At the end you can extract the values of the series as numpy array if you want (optional):

```
point_list = points.values
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: This would repeatedly do a bunch of O(n) operations (each vectorized logical check), whereas the OP's original way only does one O(n) operation (the for loop) with the slight extra cost of Python looping overhead. For a small number of logical checks, this will be OK. As the number of logical checks grows, it becomes more optimal to just do the boring for-loop. For-loops are highly underrated in Python, and exceedingly underrated in pandas.

Comment: This is an interesting way of tackling the problem. I would need to run a few timeit experiments. Current conditional checks are 48 but that can grow to close to 100

Comment: @BubaSkrimp testing with 54 conditions on a 10**6 x 10 dataframe returned 144 seconds for the `apply` method, the `for-loop` did not complete within 5 minutes and I killed it , 3.7 seconds for @checkThisOut 's solution and 2.7 seconds for a np.where solution (some thing along the lines of `df['points'] += np.where(condition,3,0)` ). My code is kind of ugly and long (due to the 54 conditions) so I'd rather not post it, but I think the for-loop is not recommended in this case. Let me know if you'd like to see the code.

Comment: @BogdanC I ended up using a similar setup with np.where which shaved time of 10x from the df.apply. Still like to see if that can be reduced further with np.vectorize for the function itself. Still working that out.

Comment: I was under the impression that using df.loc has performance limitation so I am working on using numpy for the condition and population of df['points'] column. I will provide an additional edit on my main post. Still interested to see what others have to say before closing the post and giving @checkThisOut credit for a different way of solving the problem.

Comment: @BubaSkrimp may I ask why do you want to look into np.vectorize ? The documentation reads `The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance.`, so I would be very surprised if it performs anywhere near np.where. Do keep us posted though...

Comment: @BogdanC You are right. I could not see any further measures to improve the function in terms of performance. Thank you everyone for providing feedback and helping in solving my problem.